# Process page that returns HTTP 500 code with Python/Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have issue to access some websites that returns HTTP 500 code along with correctly formatted HTML page.

So, I can download page with Chorme/Firefox, but I can't do it with Scrapy.

Scrapy logs:

```
2020-04-10 15:57:16 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-04-10 15:57:16 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-04-10 15:57:16 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-04-10 15:57:18 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.industrialmotors.com/products/toshiba-motors/where/p/1.html> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2020-04-10 15:57:19 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.industrialmotors.com/products/toshiba-motors/where/p/1.html> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2020-04-10 15:57:20 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.industrialmotors.com/products/toshiba-motors/where/p/1.html> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2020-04-10 15:57:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <GET https://www.industrialmotors.com/products/toshiba-motors/where/p/1.html> (referer: None)
2020-04-10 15:57:20 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <500 https://www.industrialmotors.com/products/toshiba-motors/where/p/1.html>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Please see screen shot below that shows that webserver returns HTTP 500 along with Web page that correctly rendered in Firefox.

[image: 50]

Test page is https://www.industrialmotors.com/products/toshiba-motors/where/p/1.html

Thank you, let me know if I should add any details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle that on only one spider:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    ...
    handle_httpstatus_list = [500]
```

If you want to handle that on only one request:

```
...
def my_parse_method(self, response):
    ...
    yield Request(url='http://example.com', meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [500]})
```

Answer (score 2):

By Default, scrapy ignores the `500` status code and doesn't handle its response. but you can override this setting by specifying it inside your spider class.

Something like this:

```
class YourSpider:
    custom_settings = {
        'HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES': [500]
    }
```

More info [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider)